# Visual Studio 2017: vcvars for toolset v140

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and toolsets `v140` and `v141`. To work with `v140` toolset, I need to set the necessary environment via `vcvars`. However, running the necessary `vcvars`, I get various errors. I am taking `vcvars` from this directory - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\VC` - as I need to initiate the environment for the work with `v140` toolset.

If I run `vcvarsall`, for example, then `vcvarsall.bat x86` or `vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64` - and I get the following error:

> Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
>
> `vcvarsall.bat [option]` or
>   `vcvarsall.bat [option] store` or
>   `vcvarsall.bat [option] [version number]` or
>   `vcvarsall.bat [option] store [version number]`
>
> where [option] is: x86 | amd64 | arm | x86_amd64 | x86_arm | amd64_x86 | >amd64_arm
>   where [version number] is either the full Windows 10 SDK version number or
>   "8.1" to use the windows 8.1 SDK
>
> : The store parameter sets
>   environment variables to support store (rather than desktop)
>   development. :
>
> For example:
>
> `vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64`
>   `vcvarsall.bat x86_arm store`
>   `vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 10.0.10240.0`
>   `vcvarsall.bat x86_arm store 10.0.10240.0`
>   `vcvarsall.bat x64 8.1`
>   `vcvarsall.bat x64 store 8.1 :`
>
> Please make sure either Visual Studio or C++ Build SKU is installed.

If I run a specific file `vcvars`, for example, `vcvars32.bat`, then I get another error:

> ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

Has anyone had the same issue, could you help?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the PATH is set? [This](https://schrievkrom.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-common-tools-folder/) might help?

Comment: @StutiRastogi the path C:\Windows\system32 is already written in the environment variable PATH.

Comment: Works fine for me.  I can only suggest reinstall/repair, and/or ensure the 'Visual Studio Build Tools 2017' is installed.

Comment: @Phil, I tried to install BuildTools 2017 and make 'Repair' for VS. It didn't help. The project gets successfully compiled in Visual Studio, but I need exactly the initiation of the environment with the use of 'vcvars'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve, so to speek, this issue using the following approach. For toolset `v140` `vcvars` tries to obtain the required data from the registry (Visual Studio 14.0 installation directory), but, because it fails to do so, exits with an error. If you add to the Windows registry the required value, `vcvars` will work correctly. In case of toolset `v140` installed along with Visual Studio 2017 this path for the default installation is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\`.

You need to locate the existing key where the Visual Studio 2017 installation directory is set (in my case it is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7`) and add the key with name 14.0 and value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\14.0\`

Comment: In the latest updates they must have changed it. Platform Tools 14.0 created a folder named "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" directly in Program Files there IS the right entry in registry, but guess what, vcvars still doens't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional command-line argument for the newer `vcvars*.bat` files: `vcvars_ver`.

To setup an enviroment using the VS2015 toolchain with VS2017 one has to append `-vcvars_ver=14.0` to the *new* `vcvars*.bat` call.

E.g. `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 8.1 -vcvars_ver=14.0` sets up an environment for *x64* using *Windows 8.1 SDK* and the MSVC2015 toolchain.

There is no need to change any value in the registry or modify the installed batch files.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/140023/view.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Microsoft forums [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/22031/unusable-vc-build-tools-2015-installed-with-vs2017.html)
modifying the vcvarsall.bat script seems to solve the issue with latest VS tool installed (it did for my installation)

In case the link goes dead: the solution is to comment line 8 (or 10 depending if there are two blank lines at the beginning of the file)

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16 10.0.18362.0
```

I just went to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`
and found `vcvars64.bat`.

After studying it, I modified it like this

```
REM @call "%~dp0vcvarsall.bat" x64 %*
@call "%~dp0vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

getting rid of the offending `14.16 10.0.18362.0` parameter. **It worked.** No messing up with the register.