# pyqtdeploy-sysroot: Unable to detect MSVC2015 or MSVC2017

Tags: python, visual-c++, pyqt, pyqt5

I have tried this-[Visual Studio 2017: vcvars for toolset v140](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939301/visual-studio-2017-vcvars-for-toolset-v140,but) it have not helped.

In cmd i have done :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvarsall.bat x86_arm64
```

---

```
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.4.5
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

---

```
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_arm64'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>pyqtdeploy-sysroot sysroot.json
pyqtdeploy-sysroot: Unable to detect MSVC2015 or MSVC2017.
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable VisualStudioVersion to 15.
MSVC2015 is 14, MSVC2017 is 15, MSVC2019 is 16.

Technical explanation:
The source code for pyqtdeploy-sysroot is in pyqtdeploysysroot_main.py
This code calls pyqtdeploy.platforms.WindowsArchitecture.msvc_target in which this env variable is parsed, if it isn't found you will get the error message